# Excel - Sorting a list with multiple rows per entry

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Is there any way to sort a list in excel if the list is not 1 row per entry. The entries could be 2+ rows

Unsorted:

```
      A       B       C      

1   Entry3  
2            Data1  Data2  
3            Data3  Data4   
4   Entry1  
5            Data5  Data6  
6   Entry2 
7            Data7  Data8
```

Sorted:

```
      A       B       C      

1   Entry1  
2            Data5  Data6    
3   Entry2  
4            Data7  Data8  
5   Entry3 
6            Data1  Data2
7            Data3  Data4
```

Comment: Try to record a macro then order column C, then B, then A and see the vba code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a magic trick. ;)

For the **Pledge**, you first fill in the areas underneath each `Entry` with the duplicate of the header `Entry`. Basically, `A1:A2` should have `Entry1`, `A3:A4` should have `Entry2`, and `A5:A7` should have `Entry3`.

The following subroutine does the above.

```
Sub Pledge()
    Dim LRow As Long: LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentName As String
    CurrentName = ""
    For Iter = 1 To LRow
        If Range("A" & Iter).Value <> "" Then
            If Range("A" & Iter).Value <> CurrentName Then
                CurrentName = Range("A" & Iter).Value
            End If
        Else
            Range("A" & Iter).Value = CurrentName
        End If
    Next Iter
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

For the **Turn**, we just sort the ranges according to column A. This is fairly simple.

```
Sub Turn()
    Range("A:C").Sort Range("A1"), xlAscending
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

But it's never over, right? You don't clap yet, not until it's brought back. Here's the **Prestige**.

```
Sub Prestige()
    Dim LRow As Long: LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentName As String
    CurrentName = ""
    For Iter = 1 To LRow
        If Range("A" & Iter).Value <> "" Then
            If Range("A" & Iter).Value = CurrentName Then
                Range("A" & Iter).Value = ""
            Else
                CurrentName = Range("A" & Iter).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next Iter
End Sub
```

[image]

And there you go. Paste the above in a module and call one by one, or modify them yourself inside one subroutine. This part, I leave to you. :)

```
Sub GrandIllusion()
    Pledge
    Turn
    Prestige
End Sub
```